# How to print / check value of vector in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I just want to check the value of the variable as the code runs (like you can do in Matlab by just typing the name of the variable). I inserted one line of code `cout << img_names;` in a sample open source code but got `no operator "<<" matches these operands` in error list of visual studio. However, I see cout being used fine in other parts of the sample code. Below is the beginning part of the sample code where cout is inserted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/autocalib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/blenders.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/timelapsers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/camera.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/exposure_compensate.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/matchers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/motion_estimators.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/seam_finders.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::detail;

static void printUsage(){ ... }

// Default command line args
vector<String> img_names;
bool preview = false;
bool try_cuda = false;
double work_megapix = 0.6;
double seam_megapix = 0.1;
double compose_megapix = -1;
float conf_thresh = 1.f;
string features_type = "surf";
string ba_cost_func = "ray";
string ba_refine_mask = "xxxxx";
bool do_wave_correct = true;
WaveCorrectKind wave_correct = detail::WAVE_CORRECT_HORIZ;
bool save_graph = false;
std::string save_graph_to;
string warp_type = "spherical";
int expos_comp_type = ExposureCompensator::GAIN_BLOCKS;
float match_conf = 0.3f;
string seam_find_type = "gc_color";
int blend_type = Blender::MULTI_BAND;
int timelapse_type = Timelapser::AS_IS;
float blend_strength = 5;
string result_name = "result.jpg";
bool timelapse = false;
int range_width = -1;

static int parseCmdArgs(int argc, char** argv){ ... }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#if ENABLE_LOG
    int64 app_start_time = getTickCount();
#endif

#if 0
    cv::setBreakOnError(true);
#endif

    int retval = parseCmdArgs(argc, argv);
    cout << img_names;
    if (retval)
        return retval;

much more code continues...
```

How do I use cout properly to get the variable values or is there an easier way?

Comment: The feature is called operator overloading (look it up! You will get a lot of good answers). The `<<` operator takes 2 arguments. The first is takes a reference to the used stream (which is almost certainly std::ostream) the second is a constant referens to the object you want to print. I will not elaborate to much here. However in case you use polymorphic types, you may only want to call the print method of the class. Then need not to define `<<` operator for all classes and provides better encapsulation. This does only apply for classes you can access (and not `vector`).

Comment: Tq! That makes googling for it easier :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator <<` is not defined for `std::vector` because there is no standard way to print that type. You can implement your own like so

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const std::vector<String>& vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        out << vec[i] << " "; // or whatever formatting you like

    return out;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `String` is because you also have `std::string` in your code, but I'm assuming it has `operator<<` defined for it as well (maybe just a typo)

Comment: Thanks! I also found that using ? (variable name) in command window in debug mode is an alternatively easier option without printing ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seealso/2011/01/25/basics-of-using-the-command-window-in-visual-studio-2010/). But of course you answered the initial question :)

Comment: If you mean that String and string could be the same, then its seems not because String definition is some sort of class (class CV_EXPORTS String) whereas std::string is recognized as the usual string variable.

Comment: Worth noting is that there likely is a good reason that there is no cout operator defined for `vector`. First, any type can be used with vector and this would impose a requirement of functions with a specific name to be implemented. Secondly and less important: IMO there is no pretty way to print a vector. there are more or less ugly ways depending on what is wanted, but in general I would like to decide this for myself.

Comment: I'll leave it as it is; "there is no standard way to print [a vector]" is a concise yet meaningful statement.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x noted, the one who is not happy with this can read the comments anyway. I actually upvoted, so there was really no criticism in the statement.